# Add delay function to existing .exe

Tags: batch-file, compilation, merge, delay

I want to make an existing .exe file to be delayed whenever I execute it.

I know that I will need to create a .bat file with something like

```
@ECHO OFF

TIMEOUT /T 10
```

How can I then "add" it to my existing executable?

I thought I could compile it into an .exe and then merge them with iexpress so that the .bat would be executed first and then the other one last, but I was wondering if there's a more "professional" way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't described how you need to use this.  Is your executable looping through a set of files?  Put the delay just before it loops back to the next file.

Comment: You can't "add a batch file" to an existing executable. Please [edit] your question to actually explain what you want to do so that we can understand what you want; when you do, remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind, so you need to be clear about what you're asking. We have only the information you give us to understand your question, and if we can't understand it we can't help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, and for my ignorance as well. Fundamentally, I wanted to be able to click on an executable and have it wait a couple of seconds before it starts. I think Kunckle-Dragger below gave me a good answer, as probably the only way is with a self-extracting .exe combining a .bat. Thank you so much for your concern and quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Put this as your batch file in a self extracting .exe

```
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 10
C:\MyApp.exe
```

The compiled.exe will self extract, wait 10 seconds and then run the MyApp.exe

Comment: instructions for creating a self extracting .exe vary from program to program, post back if get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer knuckle-dragger. I used iexpress but it doesn't work very well, as I had to first convert the .bat to .exe. Also it shows the command prompt while waiting for the 10 seconds, although that's just an aesthetic concern. And for some reason my anti-virus doesn't really like the output file! Do you have any better suggestions for the software to create the self-extracting .exe?

Comment: 7z http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/39048-how-to-make-a-7-zip-switchless-installer/  http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html